# How to group search results with multiple keywords in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have a database with keywords that are linked to a certain post::

```
Table word_index: word_id - keyword
Table word_rel: word_id - postId - unique_id


Example word_index:
1 - keyword1
2 - keyword2
3 - keyword3 
...

Example word_rel:
1 - 1 - 1
2 - 1 - 2
3 - 2 - 3
...
```

Now users may search for one or more keywords (just like Google works).

I use a SQL query, this works fine. However, when they use multiple keywords I want the results to be stricter and only show the results that have both keywords as a match. Now the query returns all posts that have one of the keywords as a match.

```
SELECT g.postName
FROM
(SELECT gr.postId FROM word_index wi INNER JOIN word_rel gr ON wi.word_id = 
gr.word_id (keyword1,keyword2) ) prr
INNER JOIN posts g ON g.postId = prr.postId
GROUP BY g.postId DESC
```

So the `Select` in the `FROM (SELECT ...)` part selects all matching items. After that it should only show all matches with both keywords and not one of the two.

Can I do this in the last `GROUP BY` part or do I have to change everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT gr.postId
FROM word_index wi INNER JOIN
     word_rel gr
     ON wi.word_id = gr.word_id
WHERE wi.keyword IN (keyword1, keyword2)
GROUP BY gr.postId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

You need to construct the `IN` list from the search string provided.  You then need to assign the comparison value in the `HAVING` based on the number of keywords you want to match.

Note:  You may need to do some pre-processing to be sure that keywords are not entered twice.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks